# increase return size elastic search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using this:

```
var response = client.Search<Document>(s => s.Query(q => q.Ids(c => c.Values(new List<string>(tempDictionary.Keys)))));
```

but it only contains 10 results max. How can I increase this to let us say 100? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [elasticsearch nest documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/from-and-size-usage.html)

```
 s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(100)
```